# Sqlite max value

Tags: android, sqlite

Доброго времени суток.
Не получается выбрать из базы максимальный столбец, делаю так:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(Groups.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"MAX("+Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX+")"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

пробовал и так

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.rawQuery("SELECT MAX( "+Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX+" ) FROM "+ Groups.TABLE_NAME, null);
```

в курсоре есть данные

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    max = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX));
            Log.d("log", "max " + max);
}
```

но когда я  пытаюсь их получить получаю

```
  column 'max' does not exist
```

база существует, такой столбец в ней точно существуют, в него  нормально пишутся данные, нормально читаются, ради интереса пробовал с другими солбцами - такая же картина. 
Заранее спасибо.

---

оказывается в курсор пишется запись с именем столбца   'MAX( max )' решения пока не нашел

Comment: попробуйте псевдоним добавить. И `Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX` чему равно?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov   Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX равно 'max' я везде через контракт работаю, ошибка с неправильно указным именем столбца исключена, оказывается в курсор пишется запись с именем столбца   'MAX( max )' решения пока не нашел

Comment: ну и почему вы решили что имя столбца в результате должно быть Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX вот здесь `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX)` имя столбца будет MAX(max).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov если использовать вариант   
Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(Groups.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"MAX("+Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX+")"}, null, null, null, null, null);

 то да имя столбца в курсоре должно быть  'MAX( max )' но почему оно устанавливается в сыром запросе, где нигде явно это не указывается не знаю с sqlite работаю не давно

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Сделайте пожалуйста комментарий ответом.

Comment: преобразовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

псевдоним добавьте в сырой запрос.

```
sqliteDB.rawQuery("SELECT MAX( "+Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX+" ) as "+Groups.GroupsColumns.MAX+" FROM "+ Groups.TABLE_NAME, null);
```

все заработает. без явного указания псевдонима имя колонки никто за вас переименовывать не будет. в mysql, в sqlite... будет в точности так как написано в выражении select. mssql для вас бы поменял имя колонки на column_0.